# Wagtail admin won't load most css or js static files

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

I have a site https://resilium.group that I recently upgraded to Wagtail 4.2 and added a generic admin view using ModelViewset to.

Now, if I visit /admin, some of the css and js fails to load, whereas it did before and I don't know why.

[image: screenshot of requests]

### Some observations:

- All 404 errors happen inside wagtailadmin
- Some wagtailadmin js will load. These are all in the vendor or images subfolder
- Some of the hashed versions will not load, while the unhashed will load:

  - e.g. this will not load: https://resilium.group/static/wagtailadmin/css/core.7ffe08725eaf.css
  - This will load: https://resilium.group/static/wagtailadmin/css/core.css
  - The same goes for core.js, vendor.js, wagtailadmin.js, telepath.js, sidebar.js
- And sometimes both will not load:

  - This will not load: https://resilium.group/static/wagtailadmin/js/vendor/jquery-ui-1.13.2.min.26d3af3a7ec4.js
  - This will also not load: https://resilium.group/static/wagtailadmin/js/vendor/jquery-ui-1.13.2.min.js
  - Same for icons.js

At this point, I struggle to even know where to look. I'm also having difficulty getting the issue reproduced locally. Everything works ok if I'm serving local static files. I appreciate any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the DigitalOcean static site I was using to build and host the static files wasn't configured correctly, so it wasn't using the Docker file that would make sure the environment for building the files was identical, which led to different files and hashes being generated than what the wagtail server expected. I made sure `collectstatic` was run inside the container, which solved it.

What I'm left wondering is why this didn't blow up immediately a long time ago... :)

Answer (score 1):

If this is a production site (i.e. not running with `DEBUG = True`), you need to run `./manage.py collectstatic`. This step is necessary after any deployment that changes static files, including Wagtail upgrades.

Comment: Yes, it's a production site on Digitalocean. I run `python ./manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear` as part of the deployment. Given the errors I get, you think it's the most likely cause of the 404s? The hashed names do match the files that are on the server, so there's no obvious reason I can see why some would be returned whereas others return a 404.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Cloudflare is caching your 404s. Try purging the entire site:

https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/how-to/purge-cache/#purge-everything

Comment: I don't have control over the caching because I'm using Digitalocean App Platform to host the staticfiles using a static site component. But I believe the cache is automatically purged on every deploy. This is what Digitalocean says: "By default, App Platform deploys static sites with Cache-Control headers set to cache for 24 hours on CDN edge servers and 10 seconds in web browsers. If you redeploy the app, any cached content is invalidated across the web and CDN servers and web browsers will cache the latest iteration of the website upon any new traffic to the app."